# Does Blender have an equivalent of Rhino's Curvature Graph?

Tags: modeling

Rhino allows to check the quality of a curve with its powerful Curvature Graph tool, like this: [image]

Although Blender mainly deals with polygon, the concept remains the same, especially when modeling organic surfaces such cars/mouses. For example: [image].

Comment: It could be simply implemented by code. I would do it in a week or so if you can wait.

Comment: The Blender community would much appreciate your efforts if you make such an addon. It's tremendously useful for organic modeling.

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/10eb529d7de33a70aa1c3febcf609127
please, copy link and try to import this in sverchok
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, blender doesn't have that type of 'graph'. The closest thing would be to show the edge and vector normals. Once shown, you could incrementally subdivide to view, and then undo to back out. If you know python, this could be programmed, but I think it would be a bit challenging.

Another possibility would be to figure out an Animation Nodes or Sverchok node tree that would accomplish the task. That might be easier but still kind of a task.